# PHP MYSQL each letter is link to another movie but when i click i get all movies

Tags: php, mysql

When I click on any link it opens all movies in my database. I want only that movie which begins with that letter and I don't know where I've made a mistake. Here is my code:

```
$azRange = range('A', 'Z');
foreach ($azRange as $letter){
    echo '<a href="index.php?naslov='.$letter.'&task=view">'.$letter.'</a> | ';
}

if(isset($_GET["task"]) && $_GET["task"] == "view"){
    $naslov = $_GET['naslov'];

$query  = "SELECT filmovi.naslov, filmovi.godina, filmovi.trajanje, filmovi.slika
           FROM filmovi
           ORDER BY naslov";

$result = mysql_query($query) 
          or die ('SQL Greska: '.mysql_error());

if($result){
    while($filmovi = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
        echo '<center><b>';
        echo '<td><img src="img/'.$filmovi["slika"].'" border="0" width="100" /></td>';
        echo '</br>';   
        echo '<td>'.$filmovi["naslov"].'</td>';
        echo '<td> ('.$filmovi["godina"].')</td>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<td>Trajanje: '.$filmovi["trajanje"].' min</td>'; 
        echo '</b></center>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Forget a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query  = 
    "SELECT filmovi.naslov, filmovi.godina, filmovi.trajanje, filmovi.slika
    FROM filmovi
    WHERE naslov LIKE '$naslov%'
    ORDER BY naslov";
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the letter to the database query at any point.

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
$query  = "SELECT filmovi.naslov, filmovi.godina, filmovi.trajanje, filmovi.slika
    FROM filmovi
    ORDER BY naslov";
```

is fetching all the movies from the database. There is no filtering here. Add some `where` conditions to this query and you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to this query might help:

```
SELECT filmovi.naslov, filmovi.godina, filmovi.trajanje, filmovi.slika
FROM filmovi
WHERE `naslov` LIKE '{$naslov}%'
ORDER BY naslov
```

Answer (score 0):

Since others have already answered your question (missing WHERE clause), I just want to mention that the `<center>` HTML tag is deprecated, and you should use [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) instead.

The mysql driver for PHP is also outdated, so instead of using:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

you should use

```
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

for better security, OOP support, prepared statements, and transactions.

You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Even if you are a beginner and you don't care about what those features mean, you should try and get into the habit of using mysqli anyway, so that when the day comes that you learn to appreciate it, you don't have to go back and update all of your code.